# Changing text in second html file

Tags: jquery, html

I have two html files, `index.html` and `grade.html` along with one javascript file, `myscript.js`. When I click the button in index.html, I load some files using jquery `getJSON`. I then want to present the data in grade.html and open it. This is my code:

index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Plz</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button id="btn" onclick="bcc()">Click me</button>

</body>

</html>
```

grade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Grades</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="para">hello</p>
</body>

</html>
```

myscript:

```
var jsonDataToshow = null;
function bcc(){

$.getJSON( "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12176084/data.json", function(data) {
      jsonDataToshow = data;    
      //$('#para').text(data[0].firstName);
      $('#para').text("good bye");
    }).fail( function(d, textStatus, error) {
        console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error)
});

window.location = "grade.html";
}
```

So I try to change the `#para` using `$('#para').text("good bye");` and open grade.html using `window.location = "grade.html";`, but when I open grade.html #para say hello. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I tried creating two buttons in index.html, one that changes the text of `#para`, and the other to open `grade.html`, but `#para` still does not change. Why? My guess is that I change the text of `#para` before i load the grade.html page and that overrites it or something.

Edit2:
Okey so I tried checking if javascritpt could find the element `#para` with

```
    if ($("#para").length) {
        alert("hello");
    }
```

but i did not find it. Do I have to load the grade.html file in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You are:

1. Sending a request
2. Preparing to do something (say "goodbye") when you get the response
3. Leaving the page (and the JS execution environment with it)

Since you've left the page before getting the response, whatever you were preparing to do with it isn't done.

If you want to wait for the response before leaving the page then you need to move the instruction to leave the page inside the callback function.

Comment: You mean i should move "window.location = "grade.html"; " to inside the $.getJSON("..:", function(data){...}.   I tried this but it did not work. Is it because I first set the text to "good bye", and when a change to grade.html I relode the "hello" text?

Comment: Any more idead?What is the standard way change the content of a second html-file?